# How to fix the difference between two time showing not the expected result..?

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $sql = "select * from patientwaiting where id='4'";
    $sss = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $tt = mysqli_fetch_Array($sss);
    $a = $tt['entrytime'];// which is 14:49:00 in my Database
    $b = $tt['exittime']; // which is 14:49:00 in my Database
    $c = strtotime($a);
    $d = strtotime($b);
    $diff = $d - $c;
    echo date('H:i:s',$diff);
?>
```

here Is My Database
[image]

The result shows 01:00:00
but i think it must be 00:00:00
Any help Please????

Comment: What is the value of `strtotime($a)` and `strtotime($b)`?  Is this due to a locale error?

Comment: You should really name your variables better

Comment: Simple test. Run `$c = strtotime('14:49:00');
$d = strtotime('14:49:00');
$diff = $d - $c;
echo date('H:i:s',$diff);` I get `00:00:00` So i have to assume both those times are not what you say thay are

Comment: Another simple test would be to `var_dump($a)` and `var_dump($b)` and see what the times really are!

Comment: Are those 2 columns defeined as TIME datatypes or something else

Comment: RiggsFolly, I have attached my database's picture ..... The datatype of both fields is "Time"

Comment: Still am trying to test with different time values. but, still the result is not exact.

Comment: I cannot reproduce! What is you PHP version and your MySQL version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$a = '14:49:00';
$b = '14:49:00';
$c = strtotime($a);
$d = strtotime($b);
$diff = $d - $c;
echo date('H:i:s',$diff);
```

When you're passing time (`14:49:00`) to `strtotime`, it returns integer timestamp for current date with passed specified time. In your case, if today would be 5th of April, it would return timestamp for `2019-04-05 14:49:00`.
Result is that both `$c` and `$d` hold the same integer value, and `$diff` would be `0`.

Second parameter for `date` function is timestamp for which formatted date will be returned. [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) count starts from `00:00:00 Thursday, 1 January 1970`, since you're passing `0` as timestamp it returns this date (with time offset of your timezone, looks like your timezone has an offset of +0100).

If you want to get difference between 2 dates/times, I would recommend using `DateTime::diff`:

```
$a = '14:49:00';
$b = '14:49:00';
$dt1 = new \DateTime($a);
$dt2 = new \DateTime($b);
$dtInterval = $dt1->diff($dt2);
$diff = $dtInterval->format('%H:%I:%S');
echo $diff; //prints 00:00:00
```

If you know the date as well, better use it and not rely on current date.

```
$a = $tt['date'] . ' ' . $tt['entrytime']; // which is "2019-05-10 14:49:00"
$b = $tt['date'] . ' ' . $tt['exittime']; // which is "2019-05-10 14:49:00"
$dt1 = new \DateTime($a);
$dt2 = new \DateTime($b);
$dtInterval = $dt1->diff($dt2);
$diff = $dtInterval->format('%H:%I:%S');
echo $diff; //prints 00:00:00
```